# How do you print out two eager loaded relationships from a single model

Tags: php, laravel

`$spots` is a result of two many to many relationships from an eager loaded query

```php
 $spots = Spot::where('posted_by','=',$userId)->has('activityCreators')
            ->with('activityCreators','activityTypes')
            ->get();
```

```php
foreach ($spots['activityCreator'] as $activityCreator) {
    $activityType = $spots['activityType']->map(function($item,$key){
        // return $item->pluck('id') ;  
        return $item->id ;
    })->dump() ;
```

What I want is to display some thing like a query like this :

```
echo $activityCreator->pivot->display_name ." made an {$activityType->activity_type}  on Spot Id  " .$activityCreator->pivot->spot_id."<br/>" ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easier route here for me is to use Polymorphic Relationships instead of like using a pivot table with 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you want correctly, you can add an attribute to your Spot model.

Spot.php

```
protected $appends = [
    'message'
];


public function getMessageAttribute()
{   
    //Assign the string value that you want to see
    $message = "Value";

    return $message;
}
```

You can access this message attribute for each spot object like this.

```
$spot->message;
```